# State of meta.puzzling.SE rules

Tags: discussion, meta, policy

So, it was [recently asked](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1513/at-what-point-has-the-community-decided-on-a-site-policy) when a community consensus is reached. Additionally I have observed a lot of users having no overview at all of the current rules, so for the last few days I have been considering making a list of the current puzzling.SE-specific rules that exist so that one is able to read through them in a couple of minutes.

Either way, I went through all questions on meta that fell within the aforementioned category and determined whether they contained an actual rule/policy proposal (a lot of posts simply commented on the situation without providing solutions and are thus not included).

## Current state of affairs:

> ### Riddles (46 votes)
>
> Per the highest voted answer riddles have to be brief and fall in either the calculation or interpretation category as defined by Travis Kindred, assumption riddles are **not** welcome. This is in line with the requirement that a limited number of answers must be provably correct.
>
> Read more [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46/so-whats-our-actual-stance-on-riddles).

> ### Copyright & Plagarism (17-36 votes)
>
> **If** copy pasting, make sure to quote and attribute it correctly. A significant set of users however is against any form of copy pasting, even if attributed correctly.
>
> Read more [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1348/a-policy-on-plagiarism).

> ### Specific logic puzzles or brainteasers as questions (26 votes)
>
> As long as there was no problem posting logic puzzles and brainteasers was allowed. Note: A lot of users currently believe that there *is*  a problem, thus making this consensus out of date.
>
> Read more [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/is-it-on-topic-to-present-specific-logic-puzzles-or-brainteasers-as-questions).

> ### Presence of meta information in titles (19 votes)
>
> Things like "[very hard], [difficult], and (easy)" are not welcome in question titles
>
> Read more [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1437/can-we-please-edit-very-hard-difficult-and-easy-out-of-titles).

> ### Questions that fit a large number of possible answers (13 votes)
>
> Questions must have a limited number of answers that can objectively be proven to be correct. Do note that this outlaws a large number of current questions.
>
> Read more [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1255/468). This is further reinforced [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1305/468) (16 votes).

> ### Requirement for explanations (12 votes)
>
> It was proposed that any and all answers that do not provide explanations should be deleted. And now there is a consensus that the answerer needs to add the explanation with the final answer.
>
> Read more [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1493/should-we-aggressively-delete-answers-that-contain-no-explanation) and [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/how-do-we-improve-the-quality-of-content-produced-on-puzzling-se).

## Needs voting due to controversial nature

> ### Outlaw puzzle-only questions (12 votes)
>
> In this proposal it was suggested to solve the quality problem by requiring questions to be either about the puzzle making process or the puzzle solving process. Simply dumping puzzles without a question would not be allowed.
>
> Read more [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1485/what-if-all-solve-my-puzzle-and-thats-it-questions-got-banned) (or [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/144/468)).

> ### Requirement for spoilers (9 votes)
>
> There is a debate over whether or not spoilers are required, forbidden, etc.
>
> Read more [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1498/spoiler-markup) and [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1359/should-and-or-are-top-voted-answers-allowed-to-use-spoiler-tags).

Please feel more than free to edit this post. It's not meant as a canonical post, nor am I expecting to keep it updated, however short term it could be a valuable page in the process of determining the direction of this site and reinforcing the choices that have already been made.

Comment: It's worth noting that, ultimately, what determines community rules is much less voting and much more consensus. For instance, if a proposal gets 10 upvotes, no downvotes, and receives no negative feedback, it's _probably_ safe to act on, depending.

Comment: There is the recreational mathematics question too..

Comment: @Emrakul: Yeah I agree mostly, have to confess I can't see downvotes here, but it was why I put the last two items in their own category. (Mostly because in the end a compromise should become highest voted if such a compromise exists, if it does not however than whatever has most support will need to be enacted). Btw, if you think I categorized stuff incorrectly, do edit/say so ;-) .

Comment: @Lembik: It didn't fit the criteria that I was applying (at least 10 votes on the question or answer), had to cut it off at some point and this was the arbitrary line that I drew.

Comment: That's because you didn't sum the votes for the many very similar questions on this topic :)

Comment: @Lembik: Summing would be ridiculous... if the same n people vote on all these questions it's still n people.

Comment: It was a joke mostly. I think one of the questions has 9 votes.

Comment: @Lembik: Ah, my bad then, reading through all those discussions after each other can make a man quite serious O:)

Comment: This would probably work better if you removed the quote boxes from the question and posted each individually as an answer. Also, I can convert this to CW if you want.

Comment: Regarding the separate answers idea~ Not against it, but I was trying to keep the descriptions short, so I would argue that that might not work all that well. @MichaelT: Wow! Didn't know that. That's actually a pretty big deal... not sure what I think of it, but good to know :)

Comment: I will note that [**there already exists an entire content section**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) specifically meant to handle this, and it still has the boilerplate autofill text from the SE creation.