# My question has been closed even with huge views and upvotes? "1 moderator is no better than 10K users"

Tags: discussion, moderation

My question "https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40586/i-have-three-fingers-what-is-this"

[Question link](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40586/i-have-three-fingers-what-is-this)

has been closed because of **jealousy of upvotes and views**.

There should be control over moderators who are acting like **GODS OF PUZZLING SE**.

Comment: Not sure what moderators have to do with this. Zero of the five users who voted to close that question are moderators on PSE.

Comment: Also (speaking as a neutral who didn't close-vote) it seemed to me that the puzzle was closed for its own protection rather than any other ulterior motive - since it had already attracted several incorrect guesses closing it would save it from receiving more. I realise it had been years since anyone other than you the OP had actually added another answer, but this kind of 'clean-up' still strikes me as good practice: preserving the original intended checkmarked answer and protecting it from a potential influx of future incorrect timewasting guesses, as so often happens on other questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question ... has been closed because of jealousy of upvotes and views.

I'm not one of the close-voters, but the reason for the closure was that **your puzzle was open-ended** enough to attract multiple plausible answers.

If the hint *(that you added after it received multiple answers)* in your puzzle was not a hint, but rather a requirement, then that would've greatly narrow down the target and it might not have gotten closed.

Regardless, "closing a post out of jealously *(and no other reason)*" is a serious accusation to make. Please understand that we are trying to keep our site clean, and everyone's cooperation would make things much easier.

Of course, if you do see a post get closed wrongfully *(and pushing it into the review queue fails to have it reopened)*, you can flag with a custom moderator flag explaining the issue.

See [The end of open-ended puzzles](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6617/70545) for more details on open-ended puzzles.

Comment: It is interesting to note that anyone with 250 reputations can vote to close. In my opinion either that number needs to go up significantly or at least one Mod needs to be involved. If too many speculative answers was the criteria, then many great puzzles (including the Riley affix puzzle) could be in danger. It seems that because of the 250 reputation point threshhold, the puzzle closings have been very inconsistent. This Amruth puzzle was a great Rebus and provoked many ideas. Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @DrD Note that I said *plausible* answers. So a good puzzle can receive many answers without getting closed, if the majority of the answers aren't good.